# Как вернуть слои в Avocode?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Похоже, что нажал что то не то. Открываю макет и вижу что,  панель LAYERS есть, но она пуста! Помогите!

Answer (score 1):

Просто потянул за край, что бы увеличить панель слоев и все вернулось. И при последующем уменьшении или увеличении ничего не пропадает. Возможно это был лаг.